# No Back Option showed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

This is my navigation.class which is also my main class.It has inside my navigation drawer and allfragments(fragment)

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation33);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_flash);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        cooLayout=(ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.cooLayout);
        FloatingActionButton myFab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabId);
        myFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(navigation33.this,Post.class));
            }
        });
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
//        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user == null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(navigation33.this, login_user.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
         drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);

        toggle.syncState();
        setTitle("Appx");

         navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        myFragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        myFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.cooLayout, new AllFragments()).commit();
    }
```

I have the answers here where just by adding                 `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` fixes their problem,however not mine.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include
    layout="@layout/content_navigation33" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_lightbulb" />
```

Shouldn't this be by default,what am I missing here?
Thanks in advance!
How it is 
[image: Like This]
How I want it to be
[image]

Comment: back option only not showing ahh? or toolbar also not showing ahh?

Comment: what???toolbar shows,the back btn doesn't, before giving -1 please read the question. @RanjithKumar

Comment: Hello I am not giving -1.. I just want to answer your question.. If you not still believe me I will prove with my downvote. (One person can one vote only). Before complaint pls make sure its right or wrong..

Comment: hi @someguy your back button is not showing?or is it only not clickable?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque thanks you,it is not showing at all.it opens just like the swipe tabs,meaning that the bar icon doesnt change

Comment: I see, could you post activity_navigation33.xml ?

Comment: also what is your base activity? AppCompat? ActionBarActivity?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque just added my app bar navigation

Comment: what about your activity? AppCompact or ActionBar?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque the one posted is my main activity,the others are parts areonNavigationItemSelected,onBackPressed.Basically I replace the coolayouT(content navigation) with fragments.

Comment: I get it,.I wanted to know what class your main activity extend, AppCompatActivity or ActionBarActivity?

Comment: AppCompatActivity @LeviAlbuquerque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the icon for your toolbar.

```
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back_arrow);
    toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onSupportNavigateUp();
        }
    });
```

**EDIT:**

I tested it here and if you add can controle the showing up  or hiding of the back arrow by calling this on your toggle object:

```
toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

Then to update the toolbar again

```
    public void onBackPressed() {
...
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
```

So if you do this:

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
 toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

Don't forget to add:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
```

This works only when:

```
    myFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

You won't get the hamburger button but the back arrow. So you need to make your `toggle` a member variable so you can access it globally and control when you want to show or hide the back arrow.

Comment: this should be inside my main class

Comment: yeah, right after getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

Comment: I sse in the picture that you have a hamburger button instead of the back arrow, afaik you can't have both at the same time. Does the hamburger button turn into an arrow when you click it?

Comment: No,thats the problem when go to the users fragment the button doesnt change at all.I want it to change like the one in the twitter picture

Comment: it does what I wanted but when I click on it,it doesnt bring me back to the homefragment

Comment: I know, I pointed you towards the answer so you could work it out by yourself :)

Comment: toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });...this exits me out the application

Comment: For what I've seen from you code you'll want to replace the fragment, instead of calling onBackPressed()

Comment: I found out how to go back the only thing now is to update the `code toolbar.i put the if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
            fragment = new UserFragment();
            toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
`